# multiple views on same page

Tags: views, theming, 8

Say I am writing a page template to show the daily special menu of a restaurant. Each menu item is a content and has a field to store which day of a week it goes on special. The page will have 7 tabs(Mon, Tue, Wed etc) to display the query of that day.

I wonder how to achieve this in drupal 8?

Comment: If you have only one node for each day you don't need views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply solution is to use 7 regions for each day and put a view block in each of them.

More flexible is a solution in page preprocess putting the view block in variables:

```
foreach ( $days as $day ) {
  $variables['view_block_' . $day] = views_embed_view('menu_view', 'block_' . $day);
}
```

And use the variables in a similar twig loop.

Think about holidays or other special cases, in code you can realize all these things. If it gets more complicated, use contextual filters and arguments as third parameter of `views_embed_view()`.

Comment: I don't think he needs views if there is only one node for specific day of the week.

Comment: Thx for the help. Just notice that there is a embed option when adding a display in view, though it seems to do nothing but provide a more meaningful parameter name  to be used in the `views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default')` function.